# InfoPath form with code behind (C#) in Sharepoint 2016 On-Premise

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

Does anybody know whether InfoPath forms with c# code behind of Adminstrator-approved form template are supported in SharePoint 2016 on-premise?

If not suggest me some alternative approaches to achieve same infopath functionalities like multiple attachment fields, print options, repeating fields, multiple views, onload functionalites in any other way for on-premise environment as my current infopath form has all these in 2013 onpremise environment. I want to move this infopath form from 2013 environment to 2016 by using any possible approach.

Thanks.